# Compile Pug Files Via cmd While Excluding Sub Directories

Tags: cmd, directory, compilation, pug, subdirectory

I want to compile .pug files in a directory, but not compile pug file located in the sub directories held within. I've run the command *pug ./pug -o ./html* which results in the following.

**before:**

pug

   includes

     file1.pug

  file2.pug

html

**after:**

pug

   includes

     file1.pug

  file2.pug

html

   includes

     file1.pug

  file2.pug

As you can see, the command compiles *file1.pug* in the sub directory (unwanted behavior), creates a folder *includes* in the *html* folder and outputs the compiled file into *includes*. **How can I stop pug from compiling pug files in sub directories?** I'd rather not target files individually.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the pug-cli to ignore some files. However, you can achieve what you're after by placing your includes in its own root folder. Your file structure should look like this:

```
pug/
    views/
        file2.pug
    includes/
        file1.pug
html/
  file2.html
```

Then set pug-cli to compile the views directory only.

```
pug -w pug/views/ -o html/ -P
```

Bonus: You get some organization for free